# Error when trying to conect mirth to mysql

Tags: mysql, mirth

I have a 500 error when trying to set a database destination in mirth service. This mirth is inside this docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/nextgenhealthcare/connect

I have tested the comunication to the db using mysql and I can conect

I configure a chanel in mirth connect administrator but when I set the database conection i get an error. First i tryied to add another java driver seting a custom lib and adding a resource in the channel.

I configured a mirth in my computer with the same version and driver and I can conect.
Anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because the MySQL JDBC driver is not compatible with the MySQL version of the server.

You are probably using the latest version of nextgenhealthcare/connect 4.2 and your database server is older than MySQL version 8.0. Probably a 5.7.x.

You need to downgrade to a Mirth version like 3.8.1.

And the most important. When you try to connect to the database it will give an error indicating that the time zone is incorrect.

In the channel connection string you must indicate the correct time zone. For example:

jdbc:mysql://remote_host:3306/database_name?serverTimezone=Europe/Madrid

With these steps the connection will work.

Best regards